# Create RDD by skipping the last line in PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, azure-databricks, pyspark

I am using Azure Databricks with using PySpark for Notebooks.

**Below is the sample of text file *Orders.txt*:-**

```
Order1|Prod1|345|3|
Order1|Prod2|45|1|
Order1|Prod3|105|2|
Order2|Prod1|345|1|
Order2|Prod4|459|2|
Order2|Prod3|105|1|
FileName|6|
```

I have to create 2 RDDs using PySpark from the below sample file.

*1 RDD (It should not contain the last file)
2 RDD (It should contain the last line only)*

Answer (score 0):

I think you can apply a filter for this.

```
val skiplast = data.last
val rows = data.filter(line => line != skiplast)

val onlylast = data.last
val rows = data.filter(line = onlylast)
```

I can't test it because I don't have access to Scala now (my job ended).  You may find something useful here as well.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.1/sql-programming-guide.html